# I am not able to retrieve list of data from firebase database. Instead it is getting listed as string values only. How can i retrieve the data

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist

[FullDbStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zViNR.png)I am not able to retrieve a list of data from firebase database. Instead, it is getting listed as string values only. How can I retrieve the data? This is how I am trying to retrieve data. 
     This is my main activity

```
        database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    for(DataSnapshot child1: child.getChildren()){
                        if(child1.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Imagelist")){
                            Log.e("retrievedsuccess","retrievedsuccess"+child1.getKey());
                            imagelist.add(child1.getValue().toString());


                        }
                        else if(child1.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Namelist")){
                            Namelist.add(child1.getValue().toString());
                            Log.e("namelistretrieved","namelistretrieved"+Namelist);
                        }
                        else if(child1.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("desclist")){
                            desclist.add(child1.getValue().toString());
                        }
                        else if(child1.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("pricelist")){
                            pricelist.add(child1.getValue().toString());

                        }
                        else if(child1.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("offerpricelist")){
                            offerpricelist.add(child1.getValue().toString());
                        }
                       ad = new Adapteradmin(imagelist,Namelist,desclist,pricelist,offerpricelist,getApplicationContext());
                        REC.setAdapter(ad);
                    }
                }
            }
```

//  This is my adapter class where I have added the code to set image and add the name, desc, price and offer price, please tell me how can i retrieve the data under "orders"from firebase

```
public class Adapteradmin extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Viewholderadmin> {
ArrayList<String> Imagelist;
    ArrayList<String> Namelist;
    ArrayList<String> Desclist;
    ArrayList<String> Pricelist;
    ArrayList<String> Offerpricelist;

private Context context;
//ViewdetailsAdmin viewdetailsAdmin;


    public Adapteradmin(ArrayList<String> imagelist, ArrayList<String> namelist, ArrayList<String> desclist, ArrayList<String> pricelist, ArrayList<String> offerpricelist, Context context) {
        this.Imagelist = imagelist;
       this.Namelist = namelist;
        this.Desclist = desclist;
        this.Pricelist = pricelist;
       this.Offerpricelist = offerpricelist;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Viewholderadmin onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layoutadmin,parent,false);
        return new Viewholderadmin(v);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Viewholderadmin holder, int position) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(this.Imagelist.get(position)).into(holder.I);
holder.Name.setText(Namelist.get(position));

holder.Desc.setText(Desclist.get(position));
holder.Price.setText(Pricelist.get(position));
holder.Offer.setText(Offerpricelist.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Imagelist.size();
    }
}

"


[DATABASE STRUCTURE][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPXrB.png
```

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo:   please check the database structure i have added

Comment: And what is the exact data that you want to get?

Comment: I am trying to get it through a recycler view adapter. where I have added the code on on bind view holder to retrieve the image, name, desc etc, But currently I am not getting the image but im getting name, desc, price  and other as [ice]  [400,500]

Comment: I just wanted thelist of  images, name, desc, price and offerprice from  the database

Comment: Plase see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, to display the `urls`, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("crazycollections").child("Orders").child(date).child(Imagelist);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String url = ds.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", url);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Where `date` is `Sun Feb 18...`.

Comment: I am loading images using picasso

Comment: Do you have an error? What is going on? Please share the new code where you are quering. Please add again a more detailed database structure including your Firebase-root.

Comment: see the full DB structure I have added on the beginning of my question. it's from root "crazy collections"

Comment: This is how I am taking the reference and retrieving data from db as on the code posted. database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("crazycollections/Orders/");

Comment: That's not correct how you take the reference. To display the urls, use my code from the updated answer. But sure the `date` child to have the correct value. Does it work now?

Comment: E/namelistretrieved: namelistretrieved[[ice]]      this is how the log for namelist is getting printed. I just need as ice only.

Comment: The way you are trying to do si not good. I showed you an example, on how to display the **`urls`**. Have you even tried it?

Comment: I am trying that.... but confused how should i add that url value to the imagelist which i need to pass to the adapter

Comment: As I see in your question, the problem is `I am not able to retrieve list of data from firebase database`. If you are getting problems in displaying it, it means that you already have the data, it's correct? Have you tried to implement the exact code that I provided you?